# How can I use Ganache to connect to a remote blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ganache

I am using `ganache-cli` to launch a private blockchain in a remote ubuntu server. I'd like to use `Ganache GUI` to connect to that server from my desktop. By looking at the configuration it only supports launching a network on local. Does it work as a client to explorer remote blockchain network?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ganache is local ethereum blockchain node with GUI. It does not provide gateway to connect to other blockchain network (ropsten, rinkeby, Mainnet). Its more like a development server/node so you can deploy and test stuff quickly. It cannot be used to make a priavte blockchain

Where as what you are looking for is **Geth** an open-source ethereum-client that can be used to start your own private customised blockchain
https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network

or you can connect it to a running ethereum network like
Mainnet.
Ropsten.
Rinkeby